# Hightcharts: Set series label in last point

Tags: highcharts

I want to use Accessible line chart of Highcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/accessible-line)

In demo, I saw some series label position on last point, some in middle and first point.

How can I set all series label on last point?

[image]

Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 1):

You can use data labels instead of series labels.

Example:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                    if (this.point.index === this.series.points.length - 1) {
                        return this.series.name;
                    }
                }
            },
            ...
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ps2ckhr/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels